# My GCE instance restarts everyday and I would like to know the reason

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

How to troubleshoot why a GCE instance was restarted?

I have tried `gcloud compute operations list` and its not mentioned there.
And unfortunately my activity and syslogs are lost after restart so I can't go back and review them in Logging view. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: The instance is running Centos 7 and its a g1-small (1 vCPU, 1.7 GB memory, Intel Ivy Bridge) in us-central1-f. I have available Automatic restart policy set to on.

Comment: Hi @goldenv, I'm experiencing the same issue, although with Windows VMs. I see a mass restart—for some reason—at 4 AM CET, nightly. Have you found a way to figure out the reason?

Answer (score 3):

I'm unclear why your logs would be lost after a restart, but you might check into configuring syslog so that logs are saved and rotated regularly, but still perhaps logs right close to the time of the event might not get saved.

In my experience (I am a Product Manager on GCE) automatic restarts is unlikely to be responsible, as automatic restarts typically do not happen that often. One possible exception to this would be if you have selected the "terminate on host maintenance" flag, which prevents us from live migrating your VM (which is why it's not the default).

One recommendation might be to take advantage of the Basic tier of Stackdriver and see if Stackdriver Logging can help you capture more information about what is happening on your machine at the time it is getting restarted. This page shows how to [install the logging agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation) on your VM.

Answer (score 1):

Does this article on [Automatic Restart](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/setting-instance-scheduling-options#autorestart) help?  According to the article: "You can review this event by performing a gcloud compute operations list --zones ZONE request or by viewing the list of operations in the Google Cloud Platform Console, or through an API request. The event appears with the following text:

compute.instances.automaticRestart"

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: Unfortunately the event is not listed in the results from `gcloud compute operations list`. That means its not google cloud initiated, most probably an app error ? but why would that restart the instance. One guess is that memory / cpu spikes are often not tolerated by google cloud infrastructure and the vm gets restarted, I have witnessed that before. But how do I troubleshoot that? Even if I can archive syslogs, I can go back, but I am not a sysadmin, any tips on that?

Comment: Can someone from the Google Cloud team comment please? I am billing enabled Google Cloud customer. Thanks.

Comment: PS. I did notice one of my vms recorded 78% CPU at the time of restart event. Could this be the cause, but I need to confirm it, also, is this a set policy?

Comment: What about writing a program eating all the CPU?